# Python BeautifulSoup4 news scraper giving odd error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a news scraper with BS4 and I am able to get the html code from the website (cnn) and this is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.cnn.com/"
topic = input("What kind of news are you looking for")
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

prices = doc.find_all(text = f"{topic}")
parent = prices[0].parent
print(parent)
```

but its giving me this error

```
xxx@xxx-xxx xxx % python3 news_scraper.py
What kind of news are you looking for?Coronavirus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/news_scraper.py", line 10, in <module>
    parent = prices[0].parent
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea what is causing this, Thanks!

Comment: The word "Coronavirus" isn't appearing on the page, so `prices` is empty.

Comment: Hey! So I tried using a keyword that appeared on the page alot like "News" And it gave me the same error

Comment: instead of `text = f"{topic}"` you can do `text = topic`

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string `topic` is not found on the page, then `prices` will be an empty array. To fix this, first check that the length of `prices` is not zero. Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.cnn.com/"
topic = input("What kind of news are you looking for")
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
prices = doc.find_all(text = f"{topic}")

if len(prices) != 0:
     parent = prices[0].parent
     print(parent)
else:
     print("No news of that topic was found.");
```

Comment: Hey  ! That worked thanks for the help just one thing, Prices should be defined under doc

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that most of CNN's page is dynamic and beautifulsoup can't read dynamically generated content. The sections at the bottom of the page are native to that url and it works just fine on those. You need something like Selenium for dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
print(doc)
```

Add print and look there not DOM, only JS and CSS